# Importing select rows from a table imported from the web using excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am trying to automate an investment proposal for a client and want to import only the first row of a table in a webpage into excel, how do I do this ?
The import from web function imports the entire table.

Comment: Can you post code from your approach?

Comment: I haven't used any code, there's a direct import from web option